# LTspice DB207 Bridge Rectifier Model

Tags: bridge-rectifier, modeling

I have breadboarded a 6/12VAC to variable DC power supply that I want to analyze before hard wiring.  It uses the DB207 bridge rectifier chip and I cannot find a LTspice model for it. Does anyone have a link to one.

Thanks, Sam

Comment: Congratulations, you get to learn how to make SPICE models!

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid. ;{

Comment: It's a skill everyone has to learn at some point, if you want to be proficient at using SPICE. You could, of course, just use generic diode models of the same type as what your rectifier uses (silicon or schottky).